# Problems adding a footer with RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, footer, android-relativelayout

I have an `Activity` with a `ScrollView` and I want to have a footer below it.
I tried this:

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

      .......

    </ScrollView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_footer1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/footer_topline"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#0075b5" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="84dp"
            android:layout_height="42dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:maxHeight="30dp"
            android:maxWidth="30dp"
            android:src="@drawable/logo" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem is, that the footer overlaps the `ScrollView`. 
I tried to use `android:layout_above="@id/layout_footer1"` in the `ScrollView` and it SEEMS TO WORK in the graphical editor, but when I try to start the app, it gives me an unknown recource error because of `layout_footer1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put the `ScrollView` tag below the footer and use `android:layout_above="@id/layout_footer1"` for it like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<!-- Footer -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_footer1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/footer_topline"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#0075b5" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="84dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:maxHeight="30dp"
        android:maxWidth="30dp"
        android:src="@drawable/logo" />
</RelativeLayout>

<!-- Scroll view -->
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_above="@id/layout_footer1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
</ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to put the xml tag of the footer above the `ScrollView`. And then you should add `android:layout_above="R.id.layout_footer1"` into you `ScrollView`.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `android:layout_below="@+id/scrollView1"` in the `RelativeLayout` of the footer. It will do the same job